# Typename Keyword for SFINAE

Tags: c++, visual-c++, metaprogramming, sfinae

I was studying about SFINAE in modern C++ which I see the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Bar
{
    typedef double it;
};

template <typename T>
typename T::it Foo(const T& arg_f) {
    std::cout << "Foo<T>" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

int Foo(int i) { std::cout << "foo(int)" << std::endl; return 0; }

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    Foo(Bar());
    Foo(0);

    return 0;
}
```

1. Why in this code, the developer used typename T::it?
2. How that typename is related to structure of Bar? because it variable is just defined in bar struct but it used outside of struct for function declaration.
3. What is SFINAE at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keyword `typename` is used here because you are accessing a type member of a template type argument.

It is completely unrelated except for the fact that if `T` is `Bar` then it should expose a `it` type member to gain access to the overload.

*Substitution Failure Is Not An Error* is a template meta programming pattern that relies on "removing" overloads that could not compile

Answer (score 1):

In the template function you put here, the developer indirectly specifies Foo is just a function to work with Bar structure (or its derivated instances). So if you instantiated it like Foo(Bar()), the template function deduced by compiler like the following:

```
Bar::it Foo(const Bar& arg_f) {
    std::cout << "Foo<T>" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But if we pass an integer value rather Bar object to the function, it will be instantiated like the following codes:

```
int::it Foo(const int& arg_f) {
    std::cout << "Foo<T>" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which has a wrong implementation and as a result, the compiler will fail because int class has not it member.

However, if you want to handle this issue, you should overload foo function for int values like the following:

```
int Foo(int arg_f)
{
     std::cout << "Foo<int>" << std::endl;
     return arg_f;
}
```

Or you can use enable_if_t for enabling a template function for a specialized data type like floating-point or ...:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<T>::value, T> Foo(T t)
{
    std::cout << "Foo<floating point>" << std::endl;
    return t;
}
```

Also, I should clarify type name just make a difference between a value and a type. when you use it, the compiler treats that object as a type, not a value because of that, the developer uses it to make compiler aware it is a type, not a value.

Also, as @Vivick said, Substitution Failure Is Not An Error is a template metaprogramming pattern that relies on "removing" overloads that could not compile. However, Wikipedia has a good reference for SFINAE: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error